# What is double-parentheses in Scheme/Racket?

Tags: for-loop, scheme, lisp, racket, evaluation

This is an example of `for` loop in Racket:

```
(define List '(1 2 3))
(for ((I List))
  (displayln I)
)
```

In Scheme/Racket, the single-parenthesis pair wrapping about something is for evaluation. But the `for` loop form above takes the first param as `((I List))` which is wrapped in double-parenthesis pair.

That seems like:

- First, evaluate `(I List)`
- Then, evaluate `I List`

What's the actual, theoretical meaning of this kind of evaluation, in double-parentheses?

Comment: It might be helpful to know that while you will see list of bindings in Scheme as double parentheses very often, Racket allows brackets to act like parentheses, and some (arguably most) Racket users would be more likely to write a binding using bracket. That is, write `(for ([x '(1 2 3)]) (displayln x))` instead of `(for ((x '(1 2 3))) (displayln x))`. Same for `cond`, `syntax-case`, etc.

Comment: the `[ ]` is in general programming is a list of something, so i now prefer using `for [(i List)] Form` instead :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a sequence of bindings not a function call.

```
(let* ((x 1) (y 2) (z 3))  ; <-- sequence of bindings
  (displayln (+ x y z)))
```

Analogously:

```
(for ((x '(1 2 3)) (y '(3 2 1))) ; <-- like above 
  (displayln (+ x y)))
```

Theoretically, either the language parses them differently or they expand to other forms (macros).